# How to manually give control of my Twitter account to my application?

Tags: twitter

I'm dealing with 2 separate Twitter accounts.

I want to give access of my one account to my other account which holds the Twitter application/API key.

This tutorial only does it for the same account as the owner of the API: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/application-owner-access-tokens

Currently it only gives the Access Token and Access Token Secret of my one account. How can I easily get this info for another account so I can tweet from both accounts via API?

Comment: I have the same question :) did you find the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter supports generating access tokens via the [3 legged OAuth flow](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth). This allows users to provide your application with credentials that can access the API on their behalf.

You can add support to your existing application or host a local web application that can obtain access tokens that support Twitter's 3-legged OAuth.

Examples:

- Python Standalone App : [twauth-web](https://github.com/jaakko-sf/twauth-web)
- Ruby Gem: [Omniauth-twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter)